# Need help creating cross-tab query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, crosstab

I've written this query:

```
select 
    poll_choice_translations.display as label,
    sum(users_to_polls_to_votes.votes) as value, 
    users.zipcode
from
    (select 
        max(id) as id, 
        user_id, 
        poll_id from users_to_polls 
    group by user_id, poll_id) userPoll
left join users_to_polls_to_votes 
    on userPoll.id = users_to_polls_to_votes.users_to_polls_id
left join poll_choice_translations 
    on users_to_polls_to_votes.choice_id = poll_choice_translations.poll_choice_id
left join users
    on userPoll.user_id = users.id
left join poll_choices 
    on poll_choice_translations.poll_choice_id = poll_choices.id
where 
    userPoll.poll_id = 51 AND 
    poll_choice_translations.language_id = 1
group by
    users.zipcode, 
    poll_choice_translations.display, 
    poll_choices.order
order by 
    poll_choices.order
```

I'm running it on a really small test database, and getting my results like this:

```
zipcode  |  label    |    value
10001    |  yes      |     1
10002    |  yes      |     5
10002    |  no       |     1
```

In Access I could cross-tab it to get a set of results like:

```
zip code   |   yes   |    no
10001      |    1    |     0
10002      |    5    |     1
```

I'm trying to figure out the method to do this using MySQL and/or PHP. I think I've seen some examples where the column names (i.e. - yes/no) were hard coded in, but I need it to be dynamic - some results will have 2 different types of labels, others will have 3, 4 or 5.

Can anyone help? I used to be pretty decent with Access, but I'm still getting my feet wet in the MySQL world.

Thanks!

This is a cross post from /r/phphelp

Comment: You do not need PHP for this, you can [create a crosstab query in MySQL](http://evolt.org/node/26896).

Comment: I've found links like this one: http://blog.jasny.net/articles/creating-a-cross-tab-in-mysql/

However, each report has a different set of options, so I can't hard code in the column names. The labels are based on ID's, so one reports labels could be 4 and 5, the next one could be 6, 7, 8, 9. 

This is why I'm thinking it's a PHP+MySQL combination. Does MySQL have a foreach function, for instance?